# how to block multiple links in robot.txt with one line?

Tags: robots.txt

I have many pages whose links are as follow:

```
http://site.com/school_flower/
http://site.com/school_rose/
http://site.com/school_pink/
```

etc.
I can't block them manually.
How could i block these kind of pages, while i have hundreds fo links of above type and not wanted to write each line for each link.

Comment: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: there is a prefix for every link i.e, school_ and hundreds of links with that prefix. is there any way to block with one line?

Comment: will this work? User-agent: *
Disallow: /school_*/

Comment: Do try it but if I remember correctly, it won't. I tried to do a similar thing once and I found out robots.txt don't accept wildcards. Also [take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833413/robots-txt-is-this-wildcard-rule-valid)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`robots.txt` is a very simple format. But you can create a tool that will generate that file for you. That should be fairly easy, if you have a list of URLs to be blocked, one per line, you just have to prepend `Disallow:` to each line.

That said, the fact that you want to block many urls is an alarm. Probably, you are doing something wrong. You could ask a question about your ultimate goal and we would give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment:

```
user-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/
```

Of course you'll have to place all files you don't want robots to access under a single directory, unless you block the entire site by `Disallow: /`

In responce to your comment, kirelagin has provided the correct answer.