# robots.txt deny access to specific URL parameters with pretty urls

Tags: robots.txt

I have a website that uses pretty urls and need to block certain parameters from search using robots.txt.

my url structure is like:
http://example.com/vcond/Used/make/mymake/features/myfeatures

How can i use robots.txt to block urls only when features is a parameter of the url.
I had read that you can do something like this:

```
Disallow: *features
```

And this will block bots from any url that has features in it. Is this true? But i need urls like: http://example.com/vcond/Used/make/mymake To work!!

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Disallow: /*/features
```

Should do the trick.  See https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt.

Also, see this thread: [Robots.txt: Is this wildcard rule valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833413/robots-txt-is-this-wildcard-rule-valid)

Comment: Note that this does not work for all robots.txt parsers, as the `*` wildcard in `Disallow` is not part of the original robots.txt specification.